# Pass arguments to serializer DRF

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Well I'm struggling at sending arguments to the serializer class, my code looks like:

**models.py**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET("DELETED"), related_name='transactions')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    concept = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='new_total')
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class TransactionHandler(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        last_transaction = Transaction.objects.latest('id')
        new_total = last_transaction.total + Decimal(self.request.data['value'])
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, new_total=new_total)
```

When in the serializer.save() method there is only the owner argument all works fine but when I add the second argument all gets messy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your serializer has field named `total` so you need to pass `total` as argument name:

```
serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, total=new_total)
```

Comment: Ahh, I thought that I've tried the way you said. Tanks !!